# I can't install react native Interactable

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo

I use expo to create my project,react 16.0.0-alpha.12,react-native 0.47.2 but i have some problems when install interactable package.Thanks for help
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F2vy6.png)

Answer (score 1):

`react-native-interactable` will not work in expo as it requires linking and **linking is not possible** in expo projects.

I suggest you to **eject** the project or use `react-native init` project.

Answer (score 0):

The command `ln` is for symlinking, but it isn't available via the command prompt on windows. Try running your project with `bash`, using a Linux machine or using the Linux subsystem on Windows 10 to see if that resolves the issue.